# Pass argument to Kotlin/Java args with Docker

Tags: java, docker, kotlin

I would like to pass an argument to Kotlin's main function args within a Docker container:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    println("Args: ${args.size}")
}
```

The Dockerfile looks like this:

```
ARG VERSION=8u151

FROM openjdk:${VERSION}-jdk as BUILD

COPY . /src
WORKDIR /src
RUN ./gradlew --no-daemon shadowJar

FROM openjdk:${VERSION}-jre

COPY --from=BUILD /src/build/libs/shadow.jar /bin/runner/run.jar
WORKDIR /bin/runner

CMD ["java","-jar","run.jar"]
```

I would like to provide those arguments in a `docker run ...` command. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do this with `-e`. Please see https://forums.docker.com/t/is-it-possible-to-pass-arguments-in-dockerfile/14488/3.

Please let me know if this is useful!

:)